# Форма в виде панели C#

Tags: c#, wpf, форма, forms, properties

Как сделать мою форму так, чтобы под нее нельзя было положить никакую другую форму, и к ней просто прилипали снизу окна других приложений?[image: как сейчас]
[image: как нужно сделать]

Comment: Никак скорее всего, все возможные варианты будут выглядеть как костыли, так как окна одного приложения не должны влиять на окна другого.

Comment: а какие возможны костыли хотя бы?

Comment: ну список окон вы можете получить, исползуя WINAPI, а когда у вас будут хендлы окон, в теории, вы можете менять их размеры/положение. Но имейте ввиду, что это просто мои догадки, я могу быть и не прав, не решал подобную задачу никогда.

Comment: [Это](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/shell/application-desktop-toolbars?redirectedfrom=MSDN) смотрели?

Comment: Даже [библиотеку в nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WpfAppBar/) уже запилили для этого